# TypeError during onehotencoder "ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types.."

Tags: python, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to calculate linear regression feature importance and feature importance with a forest of trees

For both I'm getting the error "TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''" during the onehotencoder process of the test data.

There are some empty values in the dataset.

Does this need to be processed before I do onehotencoder? Why does it only complain during the test data when there is also empty cells in training?

I've seen some suggestion of using pd.isnull instead to fix this, however this is complaining during the onehotencoder process and not during my own code.

Are empty values not supported by onehotencoder?

How do I fix this?

```
# Read the training dataset
df_train = pd.read_excel('/content/feature importance training profiles.xlsx')
#train_shuffled = df_train.sample(frac=1)

# Split the training dataset into features and labels
x_df_train = df_train[['Name', 'middleName', 'lastnName', 'Certification', 'Location', 'College', 'Degree', 'Jobs', 'Company', 'Date', 'LocationJob']]
y_df_train = df_train['Label']

# Encode the features using OneHotEncoder (training dataset)
skencoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
#sk_data_train = skencoder.fit_transform(x_df_train[['Location']])
sk_data_train = skencoder.fit_transform(x_df_train[['Name', 'middleName', 'lastnName', 'Certification', 'Location', 'College', 'Degree', 'Jobs', 'Company', 'Date', 'LocationJob']])

# Read the testing dataset
df_test = pd.read_excel('/content/feature importance testing profiles.xlsx')
# test_shuffled = df_test.sample(frac=1)

# Split the testing dataset into features and labels
x_df_test = df_test[['Name', 'middleName', 'lastnName', 'Certification', 'Location', 'College', 'Degree', 'Jobs', 'Company', 'Date', 'LocationJob']]
y_df_test = df_test['Label']

sk_data_test = skencoder.transform(x_df_test[['Name', 'middleName', 'lastnName', 'Certification', 'Location', 'College', 'Degree', 'Jobs', 'Company', 'Date', 'LocationJob']])

X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=63,
    n_features=11,
    n_informative=11,
    n_redundant=0,
    n_repeated=0,
    n_classes=2,
    random_state=0,
    shuffle=True,
)
#X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=42)

feature_names = [f"feature {i}" for i in range(X.shape[1])]
forest = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
forest.fit(sk_data_train, y_df_train)

importance = forest.feature_importances_

print(importance)
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in forest.estimators_], axis=0)

forest_importances = pd.Series(importance, index=feature_names)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
forest_importances.plot.bar(yerr=std, ax=ax)
ax.set_title("Feature importances using MDI")
ax.set_ylabel("Mean decrease in impurity")
fig.tight_layout()

y_pred = forest.predict(sk_data_test)

print("ACCURACY OF THE MODEL: ", metrics.accuracy_score(y_df_test, y_pred))
```